# Remove invalid domain names with Sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed

I'm having trouble writing a sed command do the following. I have a file that should only contain "valid" domain names. How I use with sed to remove any line that does not match an expression?

The following seems to match the lines I want to keep in the online tool I used, though I'm sure it could be written better.

```
^*.*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,15}?$
```

The file

```
example.example.example.org
01.001.11.00.example.com
asdf-asdf-asdf-www.example.net
example
example.example.co.uk
(example)
example.photography
example.info
example/
example.
example</h1>
{example}
etc.
```

Expected output:

```
example.example.example.org
01.001.11.00.example.com
asdf-asdf-asdf-www.example.net
example.example.co.uk
example.photography
example.info
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify your regex to make it valid but this sed command prints only the lines that match:

```
$ sed -nr '/[.].*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+([.][a-zA-Z]{2,15})?$/p' file
example.example.example.org
01.001.11.00.example.com
asdf-asdf-asdf-www.example.net
example.example.co.uk
example.photography
example.info
```

#### How it works

- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print a line unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `-r`

  This tells sed to use extended regular expressions.
- `/[.].*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+([.][a-zA-Z]{2,15})?$/p`

  `/.../` selects lines that match the regex and `/.../p` tells sed to print the lines that match the regex.

#### Changes to the regex

Note that `^*` is not a valid way to start a regex.  `^` matches the beginning of a line and `*` would matchs zero or more of the preceding character but no preceding character is given.  This could be made valid with the addition of a period as in `^.*`.  That matches a line that starts with anything.  But, since that is not helpful here, I removed it.

Also, since it seems that you wanted to exclude lines that end with a period, I changed `\.[a-zA-Z]{2,15}?$` to `([.][a-zA-Z]{2,15})?$`.

For other people's attempts at making a regex to match domain names, see, for example, [Domain name validation with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/domain-name-validation-with-regex) or [regex match main domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772423/regex-match-main-domain-name).

Comment: That seems to do it, thank you for the help.